# Getting rid of all the system path dependencies

Tags: external-dependencies, visual-studio-cordova

When I install the multi-device hybrid applications `[mdha] / cordova` preview I'm finding that it adds a whole set of entries to my system path environment variable.
specifically they are the following...

```
%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ADT_HOME%\tools;%ADT_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANT_HOME%\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\
```

I prefer to keep my dev workstation system path environment variable clear of anything but the default OS required values, specifically avoid using are the following...

```
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
```

The reason is that I assume it provides better performance as searches for exe/dll's not in my path return faster and I run less risk of something being found and launched that isn't part of the core set of OS signed exe/dll set that I can trust.

### Question

Are we doing anything to look at ways to allow future drops of the mdha / cordova update to operate without having to add all these extra entries to ones system path?

Comment: Check the linebreak formatting with `<br>` after the first paragraph

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty common for most of these tools, Java, Ant, Android, etc to require the user to set system environment variables, which is what MDHA does today.

To answer your question, yes, the team is currently looking into ways in which these variables can be taken out of your system path and instead be configured locally in Visual Studio. Stay tuned!

-Priyank, Visual Studio Client Tools Team

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You are required to put the locations in the PATH.

Couple of months I opened a JIRA bug to use a different mechanism to store the required locations in the PATH. I proposed to use a properties file that will store the paths in something like

```
ant.tools=YOUR_PATH_TO_ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS
ant.platform.tools=YOUR_PATH_TO_ANDROID_SDK_PLATFORM_TOOLS
```

The JIRA has not being worked so far though https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5803.